# Can I look up a users active directory login when i only know their email?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I do not know much about AD but here is what I am trying to do and the direction I am hearing I should go.

We have users in Active Directory that include an email address in the mail field.  I want to allow them to login to our site using either their email address or their normal login.  My VB code will check if they have entered text that is not formatted as an email and log them in directly or if it is formatted as an email address I want to use that address to look up the login behind the scenes.

I have heard that DirectorySearcher is the way to go but I have not had any luck implementing it.  I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

```
Dim theUser As String = String.Empty
Dim strDomain As String = "DEV"
Dim directoryEntryMTA As String = "LDAP://dc=dev,dc=ad,dc=mtaaccount"

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text) Then
                If txtUsername.Text.IndexOf("@") > -1 Then
                    Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(directoryEntryMTA)
                    Dim search As New DirectorySearcher(entry)
                    search.Filter = "mail=" & txtUsername.Text
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName")
                    Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()

                    If result IsNot Nothing Then
                        theUser = strDomain + "\" + result.ToString()
                    Else
                        ' ADD CODE IF DIRECTORY SEARCHER DOES NOT FIND ANY USER WITH SUPPLIED EMAIL
                    End If
                Else
                    theUser = strDomain + "\" + txtUsername.Text
                End If
            End If
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your code please...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed posting of code but I had to shift gears to focus on another crisis.  The above code does not work accept for the outer Else block will log in a user that does not use their email address but instead uses their SAMAccountName.

Comment: So what error do you get? And where exactly do you get an error (if any)?

Comment: The only error I get is that the Login Failed.  Nothing specific unfortunately.  This error comes from the login page we are using in DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've ever solved this, but try this:

```
If result IsNot Nothing Then
    '*** INSTEAD OF THIS ***
    'theUser = strDomain + "\" + result.ToString()

    '*** USE THIS ***
    theUser = strDomain + "\" + result.Properties("samaccountname").Item(0).ToString
Else
    ...
```

Calling the `ToString` method on the `result` object is going to try to convert the `SearchResult` object to a String, rather than the `SAMAccountName` property you just specified in your `search` object.  You need to actually identify the specific property/properties and object(s) that you defined in your `search` object and convert their individual values to Strings (or Integers, or DateTimes, etc.)